# Difference between middleware chi.Use vs chi.With

Tags: go, middleware, go-chi

What is the difference between `chi.Use` and `chi.With` when setting up a middleware with Chi router.

Answer (score 5):

`Use` must be declared before all routes under the same group, whereas `r.With` allows you to "inline" middlewares.

As a matter of fact, the function signatures are different. `Use` returns nothing, `With` returns a `chi.Router`.

Let's say you have a route and want to add a middleware **only to one of them**, you would use `r.With`:

```
r.Route("/myroute", func(r chi.Router) {
    r.Use(someMiddleware) // can declare it here
    r.Get("/bar", handlerBar)
    r.Put("/baz", handlerBaz)
    // r.Use(someMiddleware) // can NOT declare it here
}

r.Route("/other-route", func(r chi.Router) {
    r.Get("/alpha", handlerBar)
    r.Put("/beta", handlerBaz)

    r.With(someMiddleware).Get("/gamma", handlerQuux)
}
```

In the first example, `someMiddleware` is declared for all sub-routes, whereas in the second example `r.With` allows you to add a middleware only for the `/other-route/gamma` route.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [chi.Use](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/chi@v1.5.4#Mux.Use) and [chi.With](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/chi@v1.5.4#Mux.With).

> Use appends a middleware handler to the Mux middleware stack.
>
> The middleware stack for any Mux will execute before searching for a matching route to a specific handler, which provides opportunity to respond early, change the course of the request execution, or set request-scoped values for the next http.Handler.

> With adds inline middlewares for an endpoint handler.

Answer (score 0):

Let see how [`chi.Use`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/chi@v1.5.4#Mux.Use) and [`chi.With`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/chi@v1.5.4#Mux.With) example

The use case is pretty straight forward with `chi.Use` the registered middleware will run before all the routes handler which are register with the `Router`

```golang
r := chi.NewRouter()
r.Use(middleware.Logger)
r.Get("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("welcome"))
})
http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
```

For eg: here `Logger` middleware will be called before all the register routes handler.

whereas with `chi.With` you are returned new route on which the middleware would be ran so if any routes is registered on the returned `Router` the registered middleware will run. Here the use case is very specific suppose if you want to run a specific middleware for a group of routes or want to perform some operation for specific routes then for the case you can use `chi.Use`

```golang
r.Route("/articles", func(r chi.Router) {
    r.With(paginate).Get("/", listArticles)                           // GET /articles
    r.With(paginate).Get("/{month}-{day}-{year}", listArticlesByDate) // GET /articles/01-16-2017

    r.Post("/", createArticle)                                        // POST /articles
    r.Get("/search", searchArticles)                                  // GET /articles/search

    // Regexp url parameters:
    r.Get("/{articleSlug:[a-z-]+}", getArticleBySlug)                // GET /articles/home-is-toronto

    // Subrouters:
    r.Route("/{articleID}", func(r chi.Router) {
      r.Use(ArticleCtx)
      r.Get("/", getArticle)                                          // GET /articles/123
      r.Put("/", updateArticle)                                       // PUT /articles/123
      r.Delete("/", deleteArticle)                                    // DELETE /articles/123
    })
})
```

In the above example the `paginate` middleware will only be called for all the articles with `/articles/` and `/{month}-{day}-{year}` day wise route for other routes `chi.With` won't be called if there any middlware registered with `chi.Use` over main route then that would be called.